# Game with bets and a dice

Tags: c, dice

Okay, I'm a student, just starting in the world of programming, and I was going through my practices of C well enough until I stumbled across this exercise:

"Create a program that emulates the throwing of a dice. The program must allow the user to "bet" on a number from 1 to 6 (verify that the number the user bets on is, in fact, between 1 and 6) and indicate how many times the dice will be thrown (a mínimum of 10 times, and a máximum of 50 times; this too, must be verified). If the number the user bets on is the one that showed up the most times, the program will print a message saying "Excellent", if it was the second, the message will say "Very good" and so on, with the messages being "Good", "Regular", "Bad" and "Very bad", depending on the amount of occurrences of the bet in relation to the other numbers. The program must show the amount of times each number appeared.

Notes:

- Use generation of random numbers (with srand(time(0))) to represent the dice's throws.
- Consider using the pass of arguments by reference.
- Consider ordering arrays to facilitate the exercise."

Okay, here's the thing. So far, in my class, we've seen the following:

- Macros.
- For and While.
- Functions.
- Arrays.

This is what I've done so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int max (int x, int y) {  //to determine the máximum between 2 given numbers
    if (x < y) {
            return y;
    } else {
        return x;
    }
}

int main (void) {
int i, random, bet, throws, times[6];

srand(time(0));

// user introduces the bet

printf("Apueste a los dados, elija un número del 1 al 6:\n");

do {
    scanf("%d", &bet);
} while (bet < 1 || bet > 6);

printf("Indique cuántas veces se lanzarán los dados (mínimo 10 veces, máximo 50 veces):\n");

// user says how many times the dice will be thrown 

do {
    scanf("%d", &throws);
} while (throws < 10 || throws > 50);

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    times[i] = 0;
}

// the program rolls the dice and keeps note of how many times a number shows up

for (i = 0; i <= throws ; i++) {
    random = ((rand() % 6) + 1);
    if (random == 1) {
            times[0]++;
            }
            if (random == 2) {
            times[1]++;
    }
    if (random == 3) {
            times[2]++;
            }
    if (random == 4) {
            times[3]++;
    }
    if (random == 5) {
                            times[4]++;
            }
    if (random == 6) {
            times[5]++;
    }
}

// I don't know how to continue
}"
```

My questiong is, how do I finish the exercise? Supposedly I need to order an array, be it times[] or a new one (a copy of times[] at first), and then do the printing part, but I do not know how to.

Also, english isn't my first language, so I'm sorry if something isn't understandable.

Thanks in advance, to anyone who reads and tries to help me.
Greetings.

Comment: This is a really nice start :)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Okay, yes, I explained everything and didn't exactly ask... I want to know how to finish the exercise, supposedly I need to order an array, be it times[] or a new one (a copy of times[] at first), and then do the printing part, but I do not know how to.

Comment: Sorting is not trivial. Have you learned about sorting algorithms? E.g. the releativly simple bubble sort.

Comment: xing: Okay, will correct those two things

Comment: Yunnosch: Yes, I just read about bubble sort, whih the profesor told us to do. Still don't see how it will help finish the exercise, got any ideas?

Comment: I propose to store the count of the number bet on in a separate variable. Then sort the array. Then look for lowest index which afterwards has the same count. That is the number to then associate with "regular" "good" etc.

Comment: In this, you are just hashing and incrementing. @Yunnosch  has a good idea about the use of array for storing the actual values in array, sort and then count each repeated element.

Comment: @xing That would be equivalent (and more efficient) but the assignment sounds to me like "use sorting". I might be wrong though. If "consider" means think and choose the better (a plausible interpretation, I admit), then I am with xing proposal, commented heavily to explain why it was chosen after considering sorting. To be safe against professor loving sorting, implement the sorting, too. I had that problem in oral exam. I think I got my good grade only because I satisfied the sorting desire, too.

Comment: Okay, thank you both, xing and Yunnosch. I'm gonna implement both your ideas, just to be sure. My profesor has shown that he doesn't actually want a sorting in this, I asked him, but that it was the original idea. Will present both though, thanks again :D

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks one more time.

Comment: Consider making an answer yourself. Does not look like becoming famous, but should be a decent little Q/A pair.